# Не работает contact form 7

Tags: php, wp-plugin

Выводится на странице как коммент.

`<!--?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='13' title='price']"); ?-->`

Кто знает в чем беда?

Comment: Потому что обернуто в `<!-- -->`

Comment: в странице оно не обернуто в коммент. А выводит как коммент.

Comment: Приведите код, название файла (с путем) и название странички итоговой, где вы используете shortcode этот, какая-то магия прямо :-)

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='13' title='price']"); ?>

Comment: http://testiphone.zzz.com.ua/wp-content/themes/testiphone/iPhone-6-Plus.html внизу,где получить прайс лист на почту                                   <section class="soup-of-the-day">
         <h1>
             Получить прайс
         </h1>
         <section class="contacts">
        <div class="left2">
            <h1>Получить прайс-лист на почту</h1>
          <?php   echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="13" title="price"]'); ?>
        </div>

Comment: Вы вставили шорткод на страницу в режиме редактора HTML или визуальном? Если в визуальном, то WP мог принять ПХП за коммент

Comment: Через фтп вставлял шорткод

Comment: А куда физически вставили шорткод ? (какой файл)

Comment: в html файл, все я понял как только я создал страницу через админку сразу заработало,всем спасибо!